# Why won't this IF statement work properly?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Ok, so i have this basic IF statement down below. It says that if the number input is larger than that huge number that i put in it should print out the words 'I know you aint make that much.' It works when i tested it but when you try to type in another number to calculate the text just stays there and doesn't leave even after the calculation. The only way that it leaves is if you reload the page.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
    function moneyFunction() {
        var money = document.getElementById('textmoney').value;
        var dailyE = money/365;

        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ("$" + dailyE + " " + "per day");

    if ( document.getElementById('textmoney').value == 0) {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "ERROR";
}
    if ( document.getElementById('textmoney').value > 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = (dailyE);
        document.getElementById('liar').innerHTML = "I know you aint make that much.";
    } 
    }   

    function reloadFunction() {
        location.reload();
    } 
    </script>
```

Comment: Your problem is not with a if statement but with the removal of printed words. Would it be possible to change your question's title so as to avoid misleading ?

Comment: `1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`? Does your computer have enough bits to store this number?

Comment: The question is totally misleading. Clear the text in "liar". And review your code before posting here and wasting people's time

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't make that much money, you should clear out the element:

```
document.getElementById('liar').innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try parseInt to that text, so that string will be converted to Integer.
and then you can perform comparison statements.

```
if ( parseInt(document.getElementById('textmoney').value) == 0) {
    // your code here
}
```